# SQLCipher Android, set key for not encrypted DB

Tags: android, encryption, android-sqlite

I try to run `SQLCipher` over exist DB which is not encrypted.

Method I use seems to be working, but not encrypt same as `SQLCipher`.

```
public static synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
        try {
            return sDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(KEY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(
                    sContext.getDatabasePath(mConfiguration.getDatabaseName()), null);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(String.format("PRAGMA key = '%s'", KEY));
            return sDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(KEY);
        }
    }
```

P.S It's running on a custom `ActiveAndroid`

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solutions, and adopted it for `ActiveAndroid`

```
public static synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
        try {
            return sDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(KEY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                encrypt(getContext(), sDatabaseHelper.getConfiguration().getDatabaseName(), KEY);
                return sDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(KEY);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void encrypt(Context ctxt, String dbName, String passphrase) throws IOException {
        File originalFile = ctxt.getDatabasePath(dbName);

        if (originalFile.exists()) {
            File newFile = File.createTempFile("sqlcipherutils", "tmp", ctxt.getCacheDir());
            SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(originalFile.getAbsolutePath(), "", null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            db.rawExecSQL(String.format("ATTACH DATABASE '%s' AS encrypted KEY '%s';",
                    newFile.getAbsolutePath(), passphrase));
            db.rawExecSQL("SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted')");
            db.rawExecSQL("DETACH DATABASE encrypted;");
            int version = db.getVersion();
            db.close();
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(newFile.getAbsolutePath(), passphrase, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            db.setVersion(version);
            db.close();

            originalFile.delete();
            newFile.renameTo(originalFile);
        }
    }
```